# Dropping duplicates from json deep structure pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a scenario of converting excel to nested json with group by which is to extend to the header as well as the items.
Tried as below:

Able to apply transformation rules using pandas:

```
df['Header'] = df[['A','B']].to_dict('records') 
df['Item'] = df[['A', 'C', 'D'].to_dict('records')
```

By this, I am able to separate the records into separate data frames.
Applying below:

```
data_groupedby = data.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg(list).reset_index()
result = data_groupedby['A','B','Item'].to_json(orient='records')
```

This gives me the required json with header as well as further drill down of items as a nested deep structure.
With groupby, I am able to group fields of header but not able to apply the group by to the respective items, and its not grouping correctly.
Any idea as how we can achieve it.

Example DS:
Excel:

```
  A     B      C    D
100 Test1   XX10    L
100 Test1   XX10    L
100 Test1   XX20    L
101 Test2   XX10    L
101 Test2   XX20    L
101 Test2   XX20    L
```

Current output:

```
[
    {
        "A": 100,
        "B": "Test1",
        "Item": [
            {
                "A": 100,
                "C": "XX10",
                "D": "L"
            },
            {
                "A": 100,
                "C": "XX10",
                "D": "L"
            },
            {
                "A": 100,
                "C": "XX20",
                "D": "L"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "A": 101,
        "B": "Test2",
        "Item": [
            {
                "A": 101,
                "C": "XX10",
                "D": "L"
            },
            {
                "A": 101,
                "C": "XX20",
                "D": "L"
            },
            {
                "A": 101,
                "C": "XX20",
                "D": "L"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

If you look at the Array Items, Same values are not grouped by and are repeated.

Thanks
TC

Comment: Can you provide an example input and an example desired output?

Comment: Hi @965311532,   Example input in Excel:   
A  B               C D
100 Test1 XX10 L
100 Test1 XX10 L
100 Test1 XX20 L
101 Test2 XX10 L
101 Test2 XX20 L
101 Test2 XX20 L
I want to convert this into a json as below: 
[{A: 100, 
B: Test1, 
Item:[{C: XX10, D: L},
         {C: XX10, D: L}]},
{A:101, 
B: Test2: 
Item: [{C: XX10, D: L}, 
          {C:XX20, D:L]}] 
What i am getting currently is as below:  
[{A: 100, B: Test1, Item:[{C: XX10, D: L},{C: XX10, D: L},{C: XX10, D: L}]},
{A:101, B: Test2: Item: [{C: XX10, D: L},{C:XX20, D:L}, {C:XX20, D:L}].}]  . Thanks TC

Comment: @Chackraborty please post this in the question with proper formatting

Comment: Space constrains may be is resulting in this:

Comment: Updated in the original question. Can you please check this if it's visible better to you.

Comment: Thanks. :-) that works. Can you please let me know if i can extend this for one more level down: eg: the data which had an array Item and inside item, we have another item ? Please let me know if i was able to explain you. Thanks TC

Comment: Please explain your requirements in the question or open another question, I didn't understand what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `drop_duplicates` and then `groupby`, then apply the `to_dict` transformation for columns `C` and `D`, and then clean up with `reset_index` and `rename`.

```
(data.drop_duplicates()
     .groupby(["A", "B"])
     .apply(lambda x: x[["C", "D"]].to_dict("records"))
     .to_frame()
     .reset_index()
     .rename(columns={0: "Item"})
     .to_dict("records"))
```

Output:

```
[{'A': 100,
  'B': 'Test1',
  'Item': [{'C': 'XX10', 'D': 'L'}, {'C': 'XX20', 'D': 'L'}]},
 {'A': 101,
  'B': 'Test2',
  'Item': [{'C': 'XX10', 'D': 'L'}, {'C': 'XX20', 'D': 'L'}]}]
```